# Where clause on an associated model in sails.js

Tags: javascript, associations, sails.js, waterline

The Sails.js documentation [includes an example](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) where one user has many pets.  Is it possible to use the find() and where() functions to find all pets owned by users named Bob?  I've tried something like this, but get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`.

```
Pet.find().where(owner:{name:{contains:"Bob"}}).populate("owner").exec(console.log);
```

Is there a trick to this or is .query() my only option?

Comment: I guess maybe this would be added with Waterline2?  Where subqueries on this page seems to describe what I'm looking for.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline2

Comment: You can also visit the Sails.js Gitter page if you're running into errors or have questions. I've found some help there, and I'm very new to coding. [Gitter](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails)

Answer (score -1):

use populate() before and use this query:

```
    Pet.find()
    .populate("owner",{where : {name : {'contains' : 'Bob'}}})
    .exec((err,data)=>{
     console.log(data)
     });
```